# Mock method using generic types

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, mockito, junit5

Given this interface :

```
public interface JsonService {
    <T> T read(String path, Class<T> valueType);
}
```

The method is used this way :

```
MyClass object = jsonService.read("file.json", MyClass.class);
```

I want to write unit tests, and to mock this method. With Mockito, I have mocked the `jsonService` :

```
private final JsonService jsonService = Mockito.mock(JsonService.class);
```

I mocked the method the best I could :

```
when(jsonService.<MyClass>read(any(String.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(nonNullObject);
```

When the test runs, the method `.read()` returns null instead of my "nonNullObject" object. I think this has to do with the `any(Class.class)` that doesn't match with `MyClass.class`.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have strict matchers

```
when(jsonService.<MyClass>read(eq("file.json"), 
       eq(MyClass.class))).thenReturn(nonNullObject);
```

Comment: This worked by giving an exact String, I have previously tried this solution with "any(String.class)" and it didn't work, what is the difference with "eq(file.json)" ?

Comment: `any(String.class)` wouldn't work in this case since i believe that method is looking for `String.class` object, but you can try using `anyString()` method @Xobtah for to be generic

Comment: `anyString()` works as well, thank you very much for your help !